# How to tell a column to span half the width of the table

Tags: tables, rotating, multicolumn

Hi I am making a table with multicolumn and multirows. 
But I want the next line to have 2 columns that are exactly half the width of the table. Meaning if the width of the table changes when I add text in it, those columns width will adjust automatically.

Here's my code for the table:

```
\begin{sidewaystable*}[!htbp]
  \centering\small
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
    \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{\textbf{ANALYSE DE RISQUE}}\\
  \hline
    \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{\textbf{Poste de travail ou machine:}}\\
  \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Risque}} & \textbf{Indice} &  \textbf{Situation Dangereuse} &  \textbf{Conséquence} &  \textbf{Mesure Corrective}\\
   \hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Part to duplicate if needed %%%%%%%%%%%
   \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &   \multirow{ 2}{*}{}\\
   \cline{1-4}
   G: & F: & O: & P: & & & & \\
   \hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Part to duplicate if needed %%%%%%%%%%%
   \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &   \multirow{ 2}{*}{}\\
   \cline{1-4}
   G: & F: & O: & P: & & & & \\
   \hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Part to duplicate if needed %%%%%%%%%%%
   \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &   \multirow{ 2}{*}{}\\
   \cline{1-4}
   G: & F: & O: & P: & & & & \\
   \hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Part to duplicate if needed %%%%%%%%%%%
   \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &   \multirow{ 2}{*}{}\\
   \cline{1-4}
   G: & F: & O: & P: & & & & \\
   \hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
  \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable*}
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

EDIT: 
This is what i want to add. 
[image]

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "I want the next line to have 2 columns...". Which line do you have in mind?

Comment: After the table you can see I want to add a line. This line will have 2 columns, but I don't want to use multirow, I want each column to be half the width of the whole table. So the column line, will be somewhere in the 6th cell, if that makes sense

Comment: "After the table you can see I want to add a line." Actually, I'm afraid I don't see that anywhere in your code or write-up. Please edit your posting to clarify your objective(s).

Comment: I don't know how to explain differently. There is a table that you can see. Ok now I want to add a line on this table (which is not there yet cause I haven't added it yet of course since I don't know how to do it).  I want this new line which is not there, to have 2 column, with each column being half the width of the table. Does it make more sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem, you need to know the final width of table. Since it is not known in advance, it is difficult to divide last row onto two equal parts.

On basis of "trial-and-error" I succeed to obtain the following result:

[image]

For this picture I add on the end of your code for table:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Part with two columns (nested) %%%%%%%%%%
   \multicolumn{8}{@{}c@{}}{
        \begin{tabular}{|*{2}{p{68mm}|}}% <-- width of columns is guessed
            &   \\
        \end{tabular}
                        }       \\
   \hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable*}    
    \end{document}
```

**Upgrade:**
A guessing about table width can be avoided by measure of their actual width. For this I add new length `tablewidth` and new save box `tablebox`. The idea of procedure is the following: 
- store original table in `\tablebox`
- measure width of savebox
- print save box
- add table (i.e.: last row of new table) where the width of one column is computed as `0.5\tablewidth-2\tabcolsep-9\arrayrulewidth`

Complete code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}

\newsavebox\tablebox
\newlength\tablewidth
    \begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable*}
  \centering\small
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}

\savebox\tablebox{
  \begin{tabular}{|*{8}{c|}}
  \hline
    \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{\textbf{ANALYSE DE RISQUE}}\\
  \hline
    \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{\textbf{Poste de travail ou machine:}}\\
  \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Risque}} & \textbf{Indice} &  \textbf{Situation Dangereuse} &  \textbf{Conséquence} &  \textbf{Mesure Corrective}\\
   \hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Part to duplicate if needed %%%%%%%%%%%
   \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &   \multirow{ 2}{*}{}\\
   \cline{1-4}
   G: & F: & O: & P: & & & & \\
   \hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Part to duplicate if needed %%%%%%%%%%%
   \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &   \multirow{ 2}{*}{}\\
   \cline{1-4}
   G: & F: & O: & P: & & & & \\
   \hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Part to duplicate if needed %%%%%%%%%%%
   \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &   \multirow{ 2}{*}{}\\
   \cline{1-4}
   G: & F: & O: & P: & & & & \\
   \hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Part to duplicate if needed %%%%%%%%%%%
   \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &   \multirow{ 2}{*}{}\\
   \cline{1-4}
   G: & F: & O: & P: & & & & \\
   \hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \end{tabular}
}
\usebox\tablebox

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Part with two columns (nested) %%%%%%%%%%
\settowidth\tablewidth{\usebox\tablebox}
    \vspace{-3\arrayrulewidth}
        \begin{tabular}{|*{2}{p{0.5\tablewidth-2\tabcolsep-9\arrayrulewidth}|}}
            &   \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable*}    
    \end{document}
```

The obtained table has the same form as one obtained by guessing, however, now guessing is not needed anymore, the width of columns of the last row will be calculated from actual width of table before it.

Comment: +1. Interestingly, the eyeball guess for the width I used in my answer (`0.8\textwidth`, or `440pt`) and the exact width you obtain (`417.65pt`) are quite close -- within 5% of each other.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a `tabularx` environment instead of a `tabular` environment for the existing 8-column table, setting the total width to something like `0.8\textwidth`. Then, just add a second `tabularx` environment, with the same width as the first but containing only two columns rather than eight.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,rotating,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable*}[!htbp]
  \centering\small
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
  \begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{| *{4}{C|} *{4}{c|} }
  \hline
    \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{\textbf{ANALYSE DE RISQUE}}\\
  \hline
    \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{\textbf{Poste de travail ou machine:}}\\
  \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Risque}} & \textbf{Indice} &  \textbf{Situation Dangereuse} &  \textbf{Conséquence} &  \textbf{Mesure Corrective}\\
   \hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Part to duplicate if needed %%%%%%%%%%%
   \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &   \multirow{ 2}{*}{}\\
   \cline{1-4}
   G: & F: & O: & P: & & & & \\
   \hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Part to duplicate if needed %%%%%%%%%%%
   \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &   \multirow{ 2}{*}{}\\
   \cline{1-4}
   G: & F: & O: & P: & & & & \\
   \hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Part to duplicate if needed %%%%%%%%%%%
   \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &   \multirow{ 2}{*}{}\\
   \cline{1-4}
   G: & F: & O: & P: & & & & \\
   \hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Part to duplicate if needed %%%%%%%%%%%
   \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{} &   \multirow{ 2}{*}{}\\
   \cline{1-4}
   G: & F: & O: & P: & & & & \\
   \hline
  \end{tabularx}

  % snug up the second 'tabularx' environment to the one above it
  \vspace{-3\arrayrulewidth}
  % now insert a second `tabularx` environment
  \begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{|C|C|}
  & \\
  & \\
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable*}
\end{document}
```